# Google Apps Script Issue parsing number into variable

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a script which automatically responds to emails that are sent to me on my days off. I recently decided to upgrade it so that I can update the days off by sending myself a specially formatted email, pulling the data from the body, storing that data in a Google Sheet, then pulling that value and using it as my days off value.

I have almost everything working the way I need it to, but when passing the value I read from the cell to the variable, it does not work. However when I set it as a static number in the code, it works fine. I thought it was because it was being read as a string so I broke it apart and made them specifically into numbers. However this also didn't work. So now I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
function autoResponder(){
  var content;
  var myemail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  //Searches your Google Drive for the spreasdsheet that will hold your day off values.
  var searchDrive = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "AutoResponder Data"')
  if (searchDrive.hasNext()){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(searchDrive.next());
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
    var data = sheet.getRange("A1");

    // Searches for your updater email and retrieves the message.   
    var findlabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('AutoResponderUpdate');
    var thread = findlabel.getThreads()[0];

    //Checks if an update email was found.
    if (thread != undefined){
      var threadId = thread.getId();
      var message = thread.getMessages()[0];

      //Copies the data from your email and pastes it into a spreadsheet, then deletes the email entirely.
      var content = message.getPlainBody();
      var writeData = data.setValue(content);
      Gmail.Users.Threads.remove(myemail, threadId); 
    } else {
      //Reads data from spreadsheet if no email messages are found.
      var readData = data.getValue();
      var content = readData;
    }
  } else {
    //Creates the spreadsheet that will hold your day off values if one is not found.
    SpreadsheetApp.create('AutoResponder Data');
    autoResponder();
  }  
  // Specifies which days you have off. Sun=0 Mon=1 Tue=2 Wed=3 Thurs=4 Fri=5 Sat=6
  //var daysOff = [content.toString().replace("char(10)", "")];
  //var daysOff = [5,6];

  var test = content.split(",");
  var test2 = test.length;
  var output = "";
  if (test2 > -1){
    for (var n = 0; n < test2; n++){
      if (n === (test2 - 1)){
        output = output + parseInt(test[n]);
      } else {
        output = output + parseInt(test[n]) + ",";
      }
    }
  }
  var daysOff = [output]; 
  Logger.log(daysOff); 

  /* There is some code after this to auto reply to the email,
     but I've left that out. */
}
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, I gather that you mean `Logger.log(daysOff)` logs nothing if you are getting the values from the email or the spreadsheet. What do the logs tell you if you log the values of `message`, `content`, `readData`, `test`, `test2` & `output` along the way? Are you able to get your code to work with just getting the values from the spreadsheet?

Comment: @DeanRansevycz So, the `Logger.log(daysOff)` DOES display the correct data. For instance, if I manually set `daysOff` as `[5,6]`, the log will display `[5.0,6.0]` but if I grab the value `5,6` from and email or spreadsheet cell, it will log as `[5,6]`. From this I assume it is acting like a string instead of numbers, but I don't know why or how to change that. Hopefully that clarified it.

Comment: Still not understanding your problem. Is it that the logic you have for firing your auto-response on your days off is not interpreting the values in `daysOff` when populated from the email or spreadsheet? Incidentally, why is `output` a string, rather than an array? Does your auto-reply code expect an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's acting like a string because you are [concatenating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) string + number:

`output = output + parseInt(test[n])`

resulting in a string instead of a number.

```
var test = content.split(",");
var test2 = test.length;
var output = [];

test.forEach(function(e) { output.push(parseInt(e)) });

var daysOff = output;
Logger.log(daysOff);
```

The above should produce the array of number values you are looking for

Comment: That was the magical line of coding I was hunting for, thank you!